# LTC2954-2 doesn't generate expected *EN signal

Tags: power, mosfet

I would like to control part of my circuit's power with a LTC2954-2 managing a P-channel MOSFET. The schematics is based on the reference circuit on a Fig.7 of LT2954 datasheet and PB controller basically controls the gate of the mosfet and waits for the DCDC (not shown) to start providing 3.3V:

[image: LTC2954-2 circuit schematics]

My expectaction would be, based on the datasheet, that on long enough SW1 close LTC2954 will assert *EN to low for at least 512ms and then will measure the level on *KILL and decide, whether to keep *EN low or not. In fact when i press SW1 LC2954 generates super short low-level needle and drives *EN back to a high level:

[image: *EN output oscillogram]

What i could be doing wrong? I have several LTC2954 ICs from a respectable vendor and tried couple of them already, they all act the same way.

Comment: For future reference, when making symbols in KiCad, you can write `~{EN}` to get an overbar; you don't have to say "*EN".

Comment: Why is the kill input fed from 3.3 volts and not 5 volts? I mean if the dc/dc converter provides the 3.3 volts then your circuit will never start because kill input (active low) will be kept low.

Comment: @Andyaka Well, this is done according to the datasheet: "During system turn-on, this pin is blanked by a 512ms internal timer (tKILL,ON BLANK ) to allow the system
to pull KILL high. f unused, connect to a low voltage output supply "  In my case +3.3 signal should arrive much faster, then a 512ms.

Comment: What will pull KILL high if the DC converter isn't enabled? I'm no expert on this chip, I'm just pointing out what might be a problem so that you can consider it.

Comment: @Andyaka Ah, i see where are you going. According to the datasheet this chip has a built-in wait period for the KILL signal, so it drives *EN low and after that ignore state of the KILL signal for 512ms, thus giving rest of the circuit enough time to start working. However i thought, that it still worth to try your advice and rerouted my +5V coming from the MOSFET to the KILL pin and nothing changed, unfortunately.

Comment: OK, worth a try. Sorry it didn't work but, that's one item removed from the invisible list of possibilities.